# weight function_score functions in Elastic Search

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to weight each function in function_score differently. I have a regular text query mixed with a date based decay and a geo query. I want to reduce the weighting on the date based decay. On some old docs I saw a `scale_weight` option for function_score, but I don't see it any more. Here is my query:

`"query": {
        "function_score": {
            "query": {
                "query_string": {
                    "query": "my query",
                    "default_operator": "OR"
                }
            },
            "functions": [
                {
                    "script_score": {
                        "script": "_score * doc[\"rgScore\"].value"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "gauss": {
                        "location": {
                            "origin": {
                                "lat": 49.4928119,
                                "lon": -117.2948343
                            },
                            "scale": "100km",
                            "offset": "10km",
                            "decay": 0.5
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "exp": {
                        "start": {
                            "origin": "2014-06-20",
                            "scale": "90d",
                            "offset": "0d",
                            "decay": 0.01
                        }
                    }
                }
            ],
            "filter": {
                "range": {
                    "start": {
                        "gte": "2014-06-20"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },`

Comment: can you please tell me how did you enable scripting i mean did you write anything inside your yml file or anything please tell me i am searching this for soo long ??

Answer (score 4):

The documentation for [**function score query**](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html) describes how to do this, and you can also check out [this **tutorial**](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/decay-functions.html).

In summary, you can add a weight (for versions after 1.4.0.Beta1) or boost_factor (for versions before that) property to each function, and it will modify the contribution of each clause appropriately.

For your case, something like:

```
{
    "exp": {
        "start": {
            "origin": "2014-06-20",
            "scale": "90d",
            "offset": "0d",
            "decay": 0.01
         }
     },
     "weight" : 0.2
}
```

Should work - if you have a version prior to 1.4.0.Beta1, try replacing "weight" with "boost_factor."

The weight is always relative to the other function clauses, so you may have to adjust those as well to get the results you want.

Comment: can you please tell me how did you enable scripting i mean did you write anything inside your yml file or anything please tell me i am searching this for soo long ??

Comment: I believe they disabled scripting for certain languages in recent releases for security reasons.

Comment: @SudhanshuGaur yeah, scripting in queries is disabled by default, it is possible to enable it, but not recommended - instead use scripts in files